# What is the initial viewable area of a website on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, viewport, screen-resolution

iPhone's resolution is 480*320. However, it has a global **status bar** at the top, and Safari uses an **address bar** and **toolbar**. How much vertical space do they take up? Or, what's the resolution on Safari's horizontal and vertical viewable area?

[image: Safari on iPhone - How much of the webpage is visible?]

---

**ANSWER SUMMARY**

1. Status bar, 20 px
2. Address bar, 60 px
3. Toolbar, 44 px

Comment: And then it still depends if the debug bar is enabled and if a call is currently going on. Also, you can easily measure this yourself with a digital screen ruler. Awesome Gravatar by the way :D

Comment: Thanks for the tip, and for the compliment! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I measure it at 320 x 356 (but see comment on question about debug bar).

The status bar is 20px high. But you can remove that to get more space. The toolbar is 44px high in portrait.

So, by my measurement, the Safari address / search bar is 60px high.

Answer (score 2):

Not really to do with safari, but a useful link for iPhone dimensions

http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html